# crashlytics showing crash with other apps/games package id which are not mine

Tags: android, game-development, crashlytics

In my android game (ndk based and Admob Integrated), Crashlytics is showing lots of crashes but with other games package id which are not mine and don't know about them, like in the screenshot below:
How do I solve it?
[image]

Comment: it means that your json file is been user by other app

Comment: is that so? how could other people use my json file? How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

**This is the crash of libraries you use in your project just like**

> GitHub, Admob Etc.